# Issues with GPS Tracker not going to my Main Activity Screen

Tags: java, android, android-gps

For easier access here is my GitHub Link

https://github.com/PoetryHorizon/eloteroMan2

For some reason The GPS tracking works fine, my VendorActivity works fine, but I cannot access my Main Activity.  It simply just closes the app if I try to access my MainActivity.

On line 82 in my MainActivity I originally wanted to have it so if the user allows GPS tracking it will return to the MainActivity Screen, but when I set it to be MainActivity.class it does nothing.  So I set it to be VendorActivity.class and it sends the user to the VendorActivity just fine.  But when I hit back in the app to go to the main screen it just closes the app.

I've spent 2 days trying to figure this out and I can't pin point where the fix is.

If anyone has any free time and is willing to help a new Android App Developer, it will be greatly appreciated.

This is just a fun side project I am working on before my class begins.  I have never worked with GPS location before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manifest file your project is set up such that `MainActivity` is your launch activity. That is where you start! But you are also removing any pathway back by calling `finish()` in two locations.

The easy fix is just to change this code:

```
if (checkAndRequestPermissions()){
    finish();
    return;
}
```

to just this single line of code:

```
checkAndRequestPermissions();
```

And also to remove `finish()` in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method where you switch to the `VendorActivity`. Change:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VendorActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
finish();
```

should simply be:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VendorActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
```

---

**Explaination:**

In your `MainActivity` in the `onCreate()` method you are checking if the user has granted location permission using the method `checkAndRequestPermissions()` if it returns `true` you simple exit you programm--lights out!

```
if (checkAndRequestPermissions()){ //if this is true .. user has already granted permission then you kill the app! why?
    finish();
    return;
}
```

The method `checkAndRequestPermissions()` returns `true` if the user has already granted permission.

```
private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }

    return true; //Returns true if permission has already been granted!!
}
```

If the user has not granted permission then you request it. Thus `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is triggered with the results of the request. If the user grants permission you go to `VendorActivity`, however, at the same time call `finish()` which, simply put, removes `MainActivity` from the Activity stack. In this case, you are showing the `VendorActivity`, but tapping the back button will kill the app, because you have already removed `MainActivity` from the stack.

If the user refuses to give you permission you simply ash them again to grant permission or you call `finish()` to kill the app

Comment: You're the best!  Thank you!  It works now!  Thank you for taking the time to help me!  I truly appreciate it!!!!

Comment: We all start learning somewhere. Glad I could help get pointed in the right direction . Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling finish() in your MainActivity. This will cause the MainActivity to be closed. If you take out the call to finish(), MainActivity will be kept in the stack and when you press back, you will go back to MainActivity.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!  I will experiment with that!

Comment: Also, is it possible just to directly go to my MainActivity screen without having to go to the VendorActivity screen after the user accepts GPS tracking?